# Fondi 4.4 Wifi Tablet - Pattern locked and can't remember the gmail log in and password

Tags: locked-out

My Wifi tablet Fondi 4.4 is locked with a pattern and I can't remember the gmail account settings for this tablet or the password how do I retrieve this?  The tablet was locked in July 2017 and I have been struggling ever since to open it, please advise how do I get logged into the gmail account for this, the tablet does ask for the gmail login and password after I have done the pattern 5 times wrong

Answer (score 0):

If your account has recovery settings, you should be able to regain access to the account, and therefore the tablet. Understandably, Google does not want entry methods that bypass the built-in​ security. If you cannot provide the details, there are no legitimate ways of gaining entry that I am aware of.

If you simply want to make the tablet useable, you can factory reset it.